# Find all deleted devices in Intune (MEM)

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, intune

I am looking to find a way to list all deleted devices in Intune (MEM) within a time frame. I know that Intune has a audit log. However, this log only shows a deleted device if an IT administrator within the Intune portal deletes it. If a user removes the device from Intune on the client side it is not logged. Is there a way to retrieve a list of all removed devices?

Answer (score 0):

> Find all deleted devices in Intune (MEM)

Users with the below permissions only has access to the Intune Audit Logs

- Intune Service Administrator
- Global Administrator
- Administrators assigned to an Intune role with **Audit data** – **Read** permissions

Sign in to the [Intune Portal](https://endpoint.microsoft.com/)

- Select **Tenant administration** =>> **Audit logs**

[image]

Comment: But if a user removes the company device from e.g. company portal then it is not logged in the audit logs.

Comment: It will be logged but only user with the above roles only can access it

Comment: Have you tested it and confirmed this is the case? My user has the role Global Administrator so I am able to see the logs. If I delete a device via Intune or the Graph API it is logged. However, if a user removes the device via the company portal or settings it isn't logged in the audit logs.